# How can high quality custom animation video be rendered in cloud in a reasonable short time?

Tags: after-effects, animation

I would render videos like this in cloud:

https://previews.customer.envatousercontent.com/h264-video-previews/6505acb5-647e-4740-a3ec-efe9ccaffe7e/40871529.mp4

I heared about AWS EC3 and Workspaces.

Important, some part of the movie is changing rendering by rendering, but most of it remains the same.

I would renderer only a 5-10 sec video, but not longer then 30 sec.

I do not insist to use After Effect, but I need high quality solution.

Would you suggest me alternatives?

Comment: Seems to just be a duplicate of [Render video in the cloud?](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/render-video-in-the-cloud)

Comment: This really does not offer any more detail than your last attempt at asking this question.  I'm also not really sure how well it's going to fit on this site.  There is nothing special about "the cloud", it's just "other people's computers".  Rendering on cloud compute resources would be no different than any other form of network rendering farm and would depend entirely on what rendering nodes are supported by your software of choice.

If you want to ask about how to use render nodes for a particular product, I'd suggest asking about how that product's render nodes work.